# Any way to annotate the summation operator completely in a quotient?

Tags: microsoft-word, equations

Good morning, I am using the Word equation tool and when writing the summation operator in the numerator of a quotient, it applies it compactly and not as it appears in the figure:

[image]

Is there a way to incorporate it, such that using the \ sum_ (i = 0) ^ \ infty option, the summation operator shows its expression completely and not compactly?

[image]

I appreciate your collaboration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could manage was to use a matrix for the fraction, with an underbar under the numerator to simulate the division line. The difficulty is then getting the "=" to align with the underbar line.

Also, the equation has to be in "display" format.
The following worked here but the vphantom(x/x) is an arbitrary piece of spacing - perhaps you have a better idea.

Incidentally I used an \ldiv to lay out the a_0/(1-b_l) the way you show it, otherwise Word lays it out with a horizontal division bar.

```
\matrix(\vphantom(x/x)@y_t =) \matrix( \underbar ( a_0\ldiv\begin 1-b_1 \end + \sum_(i=0)^\infty \naryand \begin b_1^i \epsilon_(t-i) \end  )  @ 1-b_2 L )
```

I have a small bit of code to help insert this kind of thing starting from the above type of linear format. It's not particularly nice because the equation editor UI seems to have been written in a way that defeats attempts to paste text in then build it up, and neither the OMath object model nor MML are at all easy to work with.

Even using this requires that you have the Developer tab enabled in Word and know how to install a VBA macro. Further, because the macro uses SendKeys, you can't just run the macro from the VBA editor as you usually can. What you have to do is

- insert a new Equation in the Word document
- select the text in it
- click on the developer tab in Word
- click the *Macros* button
- select *typeEquation* in the list and click *Run*

The code:

```
Sub typeEquation()
Dim c As String
Dim i As Long
Dim m As OMath
Dim s As String
Dim t As String
Dim u As String
s = "\matrix(\vphantom(x/x)@y_t =) \matrix( \underbar ( a_0\ldiv\begin 1-b_1 \end + \sum_(i=0)^\infty \naryand \begin b_1^i \epsilon_(t-i) \end  )  @ 1-b_2 L ) "
Set m = Selection.OMaths(1)
u = ""
For i = 1 To Len(s)
  c = Mid(s, i, 1)
  Select Case c
  Case "+", "^", "%", "~", "(", ")", "[", "]" ' what about "{"  and "}" ?
    t = "{" & c & "}"
  Case Else
    t = c
  End Select
  u = u & t
  VBA.SendKeys t
  DoEvents
Next
Debug.Print u
End Sub
```

Originally I built the string I wanted to send and sent the whole string in one SendKeys statement, but that proved unreliable - I think there is probably a timing problem where BuildUp is still working and does not function properly. Not sure.

Comment: Appreciated as always your help has been quite useful, thanks for your valuable collaboration, the two explanations are excellent, greetings!